# How to use p:hotkey to submit form when pressing enter in input text

Tags: jsf, primefaces, form-submit, hotkeys

I have the below snippet:

```
<h:form>
    <p:inputText id="inputId" ... />
    <p:commandButton id="commandId" ... />
    <p:hotkey bind="return ..."  />
</h:form>
```

When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in `<p:inputText>`, how can I invoke `<p:commandButton>` using `<p:hotkey>`?

Answer (score 5):

The [`<p:hotkey>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/hotkey.xhtml) is not designed to capture <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in inputs of the form. It's designed to capture special key combinations like arrow keys and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> combinations throughout the page.

You need [`<p:defaultCommand>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/defaultCommand.xhtml) instead.

```
<h:form>
    <p:inputText ... />
    <p:commandButton id="commandId" ... />
    <p:defaultCommand target="commandId" />
</h:form>
```